# Cloud Messaging or REST API?

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the Firebase Cloud Messaging to send message to my app. I am thinking about using is to also send data from my app to my server, but I am not sure if there is any advantage in using that over a classic HTTP REST api.

I am better of sticking with a classic HTTP api to send message from devices to server, or is using a Firebase upstream message better in some ways?

Comment: You can view bellow link. It has Spring java implementation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172021/3073945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "official" advantage of an upstream FCM message, at least on Android, would be that no additional network connection is needed, resulting in performance and battery-saving benefits, and possibly easier implementation.

Depending on how you authenticate users I see a potential simplification in the case of FCM, as you may not need a separate authentication mechanism compared to a REST API.

Comment: I dont really use an authenticating system, but the battery saving argument does make sense.